# Vagrant + multiple WP: Performance suddenly dropped. TTFB = 1minute+

Tags: php, wordpress, vagrant, nfs, vagrantfile

## Hi everybody!

I've been using [Varying Vagrant Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) for quite some time now (2 years) and suddenly after working smoothly, it now takes the TTFB 1min or more... The only change I recently did was update java, downloading and installing a new SDK (not on the VM, but on actual mac)

Does anybody have the slightest idea where to look? There are no PHP errors, and it happens on all my sites in the /www/ 
(I have 30)

- VV version 1.12
- Vagrant 1.8.1
- Virtualbox
- Mac, El Capitan
- NFS enabled
- Vagrantfile: CPU cores 1

My VagrantFile

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Store the current version of Vagrant for use in conditionals when dealing
  # with possible backward compatible issues.
  vagrant_version = Vagrant::VERSION.sub(/^v/, '')

  # Configurations from 1.0.x can be placed in Vagrant 1.1.x specs like the following.
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 1]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]

    # Set the box name in VirtualBox to match the working directory.
    vvv_pwd = Dir.pwd
    v.name = File.basename(vvv_pwd)
  end

  # Configuration options for the Parallels provider.
  config.vm.provider :parallels do |v|
    v.update_guest_tools = true
    v.optimize_power_consumption = false
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 1
  end

  # Configuration options for the VMware Fusion provider.
  config.vm.provider :vmware_fusion do |v|
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
    v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
  end

  # Configuration options for Hyper-V provider.
  config.vm.provider :hyperv do |v, override|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 1
  end
```

Comment: any other update on VirtualBox, vagrant or the vvv box ?

Comment: Nope did not update any of them. Also tried it on a new VVV 2.0 installation => STILL THE SAME Ö